# How to update opam using apt-get?

Tags: apt

I am trying to install opam on my Ubuntu VM. I did

`sudo apt-get install opam`

followed by

`opam init`

but I get many error messages that look like

`[ERROR] Your version of OPAM (1.1.1) is not recent enough to read ~/.opam/repo/default/packages/yojson/yojson.1.0.3/opam. Upgrade OPAM to a more recent version (at least 1.2) to read this file correctly.`

I checked the opam website and the latest version is 1.2.2 but when I do

`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade opam`

it says

`opam is already the newest version.`

Would somebody mind explaining very simply (as in, literally tell me what commands to type in) how to update opam?

Thanks!

Comment: ? Which Ubuntu version ? ? The command `$ cat /etc/issue` will tell ...

Comment: `$ cat /etc/issue`

`Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l`

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get update` and then try `opam init`

Answer (score 2):

When you installed opam i think you used command :

```
wget https://raw.github.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/opam_installer.sh -O - | sh -s /usr/local/bin/
opam init
```

In this shell script it is using version 1.1.1. so every time you run

```
opam init
```

and it try to install same package. so if you have that shell script then open it and change

```
VERSION='1.2.2'
```

and rerun using

```
opam init
```

or 
you can use PPA also.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:avsm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ocaml ocaml-native-compilers camlp4-extra opam
```

and try to upgrade or reinstall.

or

you can download latest per-compiled binary from [opam binary](https://github.com/ocaml/opam/releases) 
and copy downloaded file to `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo cp <downloaded file> /usr/local/bin
```

and use it.

For more info : [Opam install Documentation](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html)

Comment: Sometimes with `sudo`, sometimes without, your answer is a little bit confusing :)

Comment: i just copy pasted as suggested in opam Documentation https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html